# Do File Libraries have any column types that can be modified after approval?

Tags: column

I have a Doc Library with versioning, content approval, etc. that gets updated with a Flow/Power Automate after the user has checked-in.

I want to have a column or two that are **not** doc properties and that I can update with runtime-generated data during the flow.

Are there any column types or tricks that I can do this with?

I've tried all the setting I can think of but just get "The file "X" is not checked out.  You must first check out this document before making changes."

Answer (score 0):

The document must be checked out if you want to update the metadata (If the *'Require documents to be checked out before they can be edited'* property is enabled in Library Settings).

You can use the **Check out file SharePoint action** in the flow/PowerAutomate to check out and update the columns. And after making the changes use the **Check in file SharePoint action**.

Comment: Thanks. Won't that rev the version each time (we're using major versioning)? And then I also have to create logic to not double-trigger the flow that runs when a document is checked in.

Comment: Yes it will create a new version I think. Just try and confirm once. And I don't think flow will get double-triggered. Please try and update the result in comments please. Thanks.

Comment: I hadn't noticed this before but the check-in file action has an "overwrite" option - this does **not** rev the version - so good for my scenario. It does however fire my trigger again (file created or modified) so you have to watch for the infinite loop problem (found many articles on this). I'm using a conditional check of: CheckedOut == false and ContentApprovalStatus == Pending which seem sufficient for me. For others reading this I also had to Get File Metadata a second time as I think the Etag changed as was having an issue setting the content approval status (but not 100% sure on this).